# Creating a Menu

Tags: java

I am trying to print a menu in Java. Below is my code. It works if the user enters a number that is not between 1 & 3, but if the user enters a 1 for example how do I print an option for that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Train {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Print Seating Chart");
        System.out.println("2. Select Seat");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
        
        int number = input.nextInt();
        if (number < 1 || number > 3) {
            System.out.print(number+ " " + "is not valid, enter a number between 1 & 3 ");
        } else if (number > 1 && number < 3) {
            System.out.print("You Entered" + " " +number);
        }
     } 
}
```

Comment: You probably want `number >= 1 && number <= 3` as 1 and 3 are valid, too. Or just drop the condition and make it just an `else`.

Comment: What does it mean if `number > 1` and `number < 3`? Which value can `number` then have?

Comment: `if (number < 1 || number > 3) { // invalid } else { // must be valid }` - you don't need the `else-if` portion, just an `else`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the logic for a second...

```
if (number < 1 || number > 3) {
    // Invalid
} else if (number > 1 && number < 3) {
   // Valid
}
```

Now consider `number` equals `1`.

- `1` isn't `< 1` or `> 3`, so we don't need to do the first statement ✅
- `1` isn't `> 1`, but is less `< 3` (but it's an `and`, so `1` isn't `> 1` AND `< 3`) so we don't need to do the second statement ✅
- Um, why am I here?

So, you'd better of doing something like...

```
if (number < 1 || number > 3) {
    // Invalid
} else if (number >= 1 && number <= 3) {
   // Valid
}
```

But, you've basically done the range check in the first statement, so you could actually do something like...

```
if (number < 1 || number > 3) {
    // Invalid
} else {
   // Valid
}
```

or

```
if (number >= 1 && number <= 3) {
    // Valid
} else {
   // Invalid
}
```

or, frankly just do...

```
if (number == 1) {
    // Do number 1 option
} else if (number == 2) {
    // Do number 2 option
} else if (number == 3) {
    // Do number 3 option
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

This commonly known as "happy path" - you do what you're expecting first and then handle the "how did I get here!?" cases lasts.

I just want to point out that "desk checking" your code is really, really important for catching these kind of issues.  You could also use `print` statements are even run through the debugger, all of which will help you better understand what you've done wrong.

Comment: @user16320675 yeah, I thought that too, but I figured I’ve probably confused op enough 